# How would I make ajax wait with setTimeout within a switch case

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How do I make ajax wait 20 seconds before showing the next chat line. What I am trying to do is make ajax wait a few seconds before sending the next chatline.

Let's say for example that there are 3 users logged in and that all three of them submit a chat at the exact same time. Let's us say that user1 sent 'Hi', user2 sent 'hello', and user3 sent 'okay'. All three of them submitted at the same time and what this program does is it gets all the chats that it finds in the database in a certain time lapse and prints them. What I want it to do is wait a few seconds before printing all the data that it reads in the database.

for example it should be printing the imput from user1, user2, and user3 at different intervals

'Hi'
//waits 30 seconds then prints next message
'hello'
//waits another 30 seconds then prints next message
'okay'
//waits another 30 seconds if there are more messeges during this interval

index.html

```
<body>

    <div id="chatContainer">

        <div id="chatTopBar" class="rounded"></div>
        <div id="chatLineHolder"></div>

        <div id="chatUsers" class="rounded"></div>
        <div id="chatBottomBar" class="rounded">
            <div class="tip"></div>

            <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="">
                <input id="name" name="name" class="rounded" maxlength="16" />
                <input id="email" name="email" class="rounded" />
                <input type="submit" class="blueButton" value="Login" />
            </form>

            <form id="submitForm" method="post" action="">
                <input id="chatText" name="chatText" class="rounded" maxlength="255" />
                <input type="submit" class="blueButton" value="Submit" />
            </form>

        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jScrollPane/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
```

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Run the init method on document ready:
    chat.init();

});

var chat = {

    // data holds variables for use in the class:

    data : {
        lastID      : 0,
        noActivity  : 0
    },

    // Init binds event listeners and sets up timers:

    init : function(){


        // Converting the #chatLineHolder div into a jScrollPane,
        // and saving the plugin's API in chat.data:

        chat.data.jspAPI = $('#chatLineHolder').jScrollPane({
            verticalDragMinHeight: 12,
            verticalDragMaxHeight: 12
        }).data('jsp');

        // We use the working variable to prevent
        // multiple form submissions:

        var working = false;

        // Self executing timeout functions

        (function getChatsTimeoutFunction(){
            chat.getChats(getChatsTimeoutFunction);
        })();

        (function getUsersTimeoutFunction(){
            chat.getUsers(getUsersTimeoutFunction);
        })();

    },


    // The render method generates the HTML markup 
    // that is needed by the other methods:

    render : function(template,params){

        var arr = [];
        switch(template){
            case 'loginTopBar':
                arr = [
                '<span><img src="',params.gravatar,'" width="23" height="23" />',
                '<span class="name">',params.name,
                '</span><a href="" class="logoutButton rounded">Logout</a></span>'];
            break;

            case 'chatLine':
                arr = [
                    '<div class="chat chat-',params.id,' rounded"><span class="gravatar"><img src="',params.gravatar,
                    '" width="23" height="23" onload="this.style.visibility=\'visible\'" />','</span><span class="author">',params.author,
                    ':</span><span class="text">',params.text,'</span><span class="time">',params.time,'</span></div>'];
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
// I have tried to do a setTimeout here but it does not delay the message
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
            break;

            case 'user':
                arr = [
                    '<div class="user" title="',params.name,'"><img src="',
                    params.gravatar,'" width="30" height="30" onload="this.style.visibility=\'visible\'" /></div>'
                ];
            break;
        }

        return arr.join('');

    },

    // The addChatLine method ads a chat entry to the page

    addChatLine : function(params){

        // All times are displayed in the user's timezone

        var d = new Date();
        if(params.time) {

            // PHP returns the time in UTC (GMT). We use it to feed the date
            // object and later output it in the user's timezone. JavaScript
            // internally converts it for us.

            d.setUTCHours(params.time.hours,params.time.minutes);
        }

        params.time = (d.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '' ) + d.getHours()+':'+
                      (d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0':'') + d.getMinutes();

        var markup = chat.render('chatLine',params),
            exists = $('#chatLineHolder .chat-'+params.id);

        if(exists.length){
            exists.remove();
        }

        if(!chat.data.lastID){
            // If this is the first chat, remove the
            // paragraph saying there aren't any:

            $('#chatLineHolder p').remove();
        }

        // If this isn't a temporary chat:
        if(params.id.toString().charAt(0) != 't'){
            var previous = $('#chatLineHolder .chat-'+(+params.id - 1));
            if(previous.length){
                previous.after(markup);
            }
            else chat.data.jspAPI.getContentPane().append(markup);
        }
        else chat.data.jspAPI.getContentPane().append(markup);

        // As we added new content, we need to
        // reinitialise the jScrollPane plugin:

        chat.data.jspAPI.reinitialise();
        chat.data.jspAPI.scrollToBottom(true);

    },

    // This method requests the latest chats
    // (since lastID), and adds them to the page.

    getChats : function(callback){
        $.tzGET('getChats',{lastID: chat.data.lastID},function(r){

            for(var i=0;i<r.chats.length;i++){
                chat.addChatLine(r.chats[i]);
            }

            if(r.chats.length){
                chat.data.noActivity = 0;
                chat.data.lastID = r.chats[i-1].id;
            }
            else{
                // If no chats were received, increment
                // the noActivity counter.

                chat.data.noActivity++;
            }

            if(!chat.data.lastID){
                chat.data.jspAPI.getContentPane().html('<p class="noChats">No chats yet</p>');
            }

            // Setting a timeout for the next request,
            // depending on the chat activity:

            var nextRequest = 1000;

            // 2 seconds
            if(chat.data.noActivity > 3){
                nextRequest = 2000;
            }

            if(chat.data.noActivity > 10){
                nextRequest = 5000;
            }

            // 15 seconds
            if(chat.data.noActivity > 20){
                nextRequest = 15000;
            }

            setTimeout(callback,nextRequest);
        });
    },

};

// Custom GET & POST wrappers:

$.tzPOST = function(action,data,callback){
    $.post('php/ajax.php?action='+action,data,callback,'json');
}

$.tzGET = function(action,data,callback){
    $.get('php/ajax.php?action='+action,data,callback,'json');
}

// A custom jQuery method for placeholder text:

$.fn.defaultText = function(value){

    var element = this.eq(0);
    element.data('defaultText',value);

    element.focus(function(){
        if(element.val() == value){
            element.val('').removeClass('defaultText');
        }
    }).blur(function(){
        if(element.val() == '' || element.val() == value){
            element.addClass('defaultText').val(value);
        }
    });

    return element.blur();
}
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

/* Database Configuration. Add your details below */

$dbOptions = array(
    'db_host' => '',
    'db_user' => '',
    'db_pass' => '',
    'db_name' => ''
);

/* Database Config End */


error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

require "classes/DB.class.php";
require "classes/Chat.class.php";
require "classes/ChatBase.class.php";
require "classes/ChatLine.class.php";
require "classes/ChatUser.class.php";

session_name('webchat');
session_start();

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){

    // If magic quotes is enabled, strip the extra slashes
    array_walk_recursive($_GET,create_function('&$v,$k','$v = stripslashes($v);'));
    array_walk_recursive($_POST,create_function('&$v,$k','$v = stripslashes($v);'));
}

try{

    // Connecting to the database
    DB::init($dbOptions);

    $response = array();

    // Handling the supported actions:

    switch($_GET['action']){

        case 'login':
            $response = Chat::login($_POST['name'],$_POST['email']);
        break;

        case 'checkLogged':
            $response = Chat::checkLogged();
        break;

        case 'logout':
            $response = Chat::logout();
        break;

        case 'submitChat':
            $response = Chat::submitChat($_POST['chatText']);
        break;

        case 'getUsers':
            $response = Chat::getUsers();
        break;

        case 'getChats':
            $response = Chat::getChats($_GET['lastID']);
        break;

        default:
            throw new Exception('Wrong action');
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die(json_encode(array('error' => $e->getMessage())));
}

?>
```

Chat.class.php

```
<?php

/* The Chat class exploses public static methods, used by ajax.php */

class Chat{


    public static function getChats($lastID){
        $lastID = (int)$lastID;

        $result = DB::query('SELECT * FROM webchat_lines WHERE id > '.$lastID.' ORDER BY id ASC');

        $chats = array();
        while($chat = $result->fetch_object()){

            // Returning the GMT (UTC) time of the chat creation:

            $chat->time = array(
                'hours'     => gmdate('H',strtotime($chat->ts)),
                'minutes'   => gmdate('i',strtotime($chat->ts))
            );

            $chat->gravatar = Chat::gravatarFromHash($chat->gravatar);

            $chats[] = $chat;
        }

        return array('chats' => $chats);
    }

    public static function gravatarFromHash($hash, $size=23){
        return 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.$hash.'?size='.$size.'&amp;default='.
                urlencode('http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536?size='.$size);
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: What is the exact reason you want to do this? To be honest I think it would be pretty bad (understatement) for the user experience of your chat client...

Comment: I want to save the data of the message somewhere else before displaying it to the user. but it takes some time for it to load and save in the other page. @BarryMeijer

Comment: In that case the problem lies elsewhere... You should split some things. For a project of my own I once had to build an Omegle like chatclient. When the user posts a message it gets saved in the database and another piece of code was checking for new messages every 500 ms. My point is that more then 1 second would be too much...

Comment: @BarryMeijer for now I just want it to wait a few seconds before displaying the messages. I've been trying this for the past week but to no success. I tried making ajax that sends data to a php file and then sleeps but it did not respect the sleep method and kept running and such

Comment: Javascript does not support a sleep method. Each code snippet runs to completion in a thread before another piece of code can run. A call to setTimeout just enqueues the supplied function _and continues to the next line of code without waiting_. Sounds like an algorithm design problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, you want to display each chat message on the screen 30 seconds apart from each other. If that is the case you can set a timeout in your for loop. See comments in code snippet below:

```
// This method requests the latest chats
// (since lastID), and adds them to the page.

getChats : function(callback){
    $.tzGET('getChats',{lastID: chat.data.lastID},function(r){

        /***** REPLACE THIS
        for(var i=0;i<r.chats.length;i++){
            chat.addChatLine(r.chats[i]);
        }
        *****/


        /***** WITH THIS *****/
        for (var i = 0; i <= r.chats.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(function(x) {
                return function() {
                    console.log(x);
                    chat.addChatLine(r.chats[x]);
                };
            }(i), 30000*i);
        }
        /***** END EXAMPLE *****/


        if(r.chats.length){
            chat.data.noActivity = 0;
            chat.data.lastID = r.chats[i-1].id;
        }
        else{
            // If no chats were received, increment
            // the noActivity counter.

            chat.data.noActivity++;
        }

        if(!chat.data.lastID){
            chat.data.jspAPI.getContentPane().html('<p class="noChats">No chats yet</p>');
        }

        // Setting a timeout for the next request,
        // depending on the chat activity:

        var nextRequest = 1000;

        // 2 seconds
        if(chat.data.noActivity > 3){
            nextRequest = 2000;
        }

        if(chat.data.noActivity > 10){
            nextRequest = 5000;
        }

        // 15 seconds
        if(chat.data.noActivity > 20){
            nextRequest = 15000;
        }

        setTimeout(callback,nextRequest);
    });
},
```

Since a normal setTimeout function in a for loop will just output the same index over and over, we need to wrap the original anonymous function in another one. In the outer anonymous function, we take in a parameter x and pass x into chat.addChatLine(). We execute the outer function immediately during each loop and pass the value of i into it. The outer function then returns the original anonymous function to be used for setTimeout() with the value of i captured in its private variable x.

Comment: This may work but it doesn't answer the question how it can be done in a `switch-case`. If you could edit your answer to better fit the question that would be great.